# Peer-to-Peer CUDA transfers

Tags: cuda, p2p, nvidia, bandwidth, pci-e

I heard about peer-to-peer memory transfers and read something about it but could not really understand how much fast this is compared to standard PCI-E bus transfers.

I have a CUDA application which uses more than one gpu and I might be interested in P2P transfers. My question is: how fast is it compared to PCI-E? Can I use it often to have two devices communicate with each other?

Comment: `p2p` is just market speak for saying CUDA devices can now transfer data between each other over PCI-E. The speeds will be what you expect from your PCI-E bus. On a more interesting side there is also something called "peer access" which lets you launch a kernel that can read / write data from multiple devices.

Comment: This is interesting.. can you point me to something that describes this "peer access" ? Also: make this an answer, it is sufficient to me and I'll accept it!

Comment: Added an answer with links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A CUDA "peer" refers to another GPU that is capable of accessing data from the current GPU. All GPUs with compute 2.0 and greater have this feature enabled.

*Peer to peer* memory copies involve using `cudaMemcpy` to copy memory over PCI-E as shown below.

```
cudaMemcpy(dst, src, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

Note that `dst` and `src` can be on different devices.

[`cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__PEER_g9e5ea65a18938c2b8715a5602105c306.html) enables the user to launch a kernel that uses data from multiple devices. The memory accesses are still done over PCI-E and will have the same bottlenecks.

A good example of this would be [simplep2p](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#simple-peer-to-peer-transfers-with-multi-gpu) from the cuda samples.